# MongoDB How to check if all ObjectIds inside the array exist in the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array containing multiple mongodb ObjectId, how can I know if all that Ids exist in the specific collection,

Although I can achieve my expected result by for loop like this, it will take too long to load because it will make multiple query for how many index my array has.

```js
const queryData = async objectIds => {
    // objectIds contains an array of ObjectId

    for (let i = 0; i < objectIds.length; i++) {
        const objId = objectIds[i]
        const data = await DataCollection.findOne({ _id: objId })

        if (!data) throw new Error('Data not found!')
    }
}
```

how can I achieve the same result as my sample function without querying multiple times that makes the process so much slower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#count-all-documents-that-match-a-query) and [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) for filtering condition:

```
let count = await DataCollection.count( { _id: { $in: objectIds } } );
let all = count === objectIds.length;
```